# apply function to generate multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a function which return multiple fields from network, I would like generate multiple columns base on that data.

Below sample work as expected but the function call has been done repeatly.

Any better way to only call fetch function one time for each row instead of repeat it for new columns?

```
import pandas as pd 

def fetch(x):
    return [x*2,x*3]

data = [
    [1],    
    [2],    
    [3]
    ]

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['x'])

df['y'] = df['x'].apply(lambda x: fetch(x)[0])
df['z'] = df['x'].apply(lambda x: fetch(x)[1])
    
print(df)
```